# Push view to navigation from modal of another tab

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I'm quite new to iOS programming and I'm trying to do something that I think is simple but I can't find clear explanation. 
I'm trying to develop an app with Xcode 6.3 and swift 1.2

I have this :

[image: storyboard in xcode]

So I'm in a tab based application. Each tab view are inside navigation controller. 
**D** is a modal launch from **C**. When I click on a button inside **D** I want to go to **B**. This is fine. But I would like also to display the top navigation bar with a back button pointing to **A**.
For now when I tried to use the push segue from **D** to **B**, **B** is shown as modal but not part of the navigation controller.

How I have to achieve this easily ? Do I have to recreate all the stack by instantiating each view (A then B) and push everything onto the navigation stack ?

If you know the code to achieve this in objective-c it's fine for me as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*When I click on a button inside **D** I want to go to **B**. This is fine. But I would like also to display the top navigation bar with a back button pointing to **A**.*

You can only go *back* to **A**, if it is actually on the *navigation stack*. So, you will have to somehow push it onto the stack before you can achieve your goal.

As a general hint, if you want a view controller to show the navigation bar, you only have to make sure it's embedded into a navigation controller. When you present a view modally, it will not by default be embedded into a navigation controller. So, as you said **D** is shown modally from **C**, just embed **D** into another navigation controller and instead of making **D** the destination for the modal segue, make the navigation controller the destination.

**Update**

If you want to show a back button in **B** that points to **A**, *even though **B** was shown modally from **D***, you will have to hack your way around because **A** is not on the navigation stack. So, logically, what you have to do is make sure that **A** is on the navigation stack just before **B**. I don't think you can do this simply with segues from IB, but rather use code and instantiate the `UINavigationController` yourself:

```
- (void)showBModallyWithBackButtonToA
{
    A *a = [[A alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:a];
    B *b = [[B alloc] init];
    [nav pushViewController:b animated:NO];
    [self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

This code has to be executed from **D**, if I understand your setup correctly.

Comment: Thanks nburk for the answer but it's not clear to me. If I do that, B back button inside nav bar will point to D instead of A no ?

Comment: the back button _always_ points to the previous view controller if you used a push segue, that's default behaviour that you can't change. modal segues don't have any back buttons, here, you as the developer are responsible for giving the user the possibility to perform any actions (e.g. dismiss the modal view)

Comment: Yes, but so it does not solve my problem. what I want to achieve is to set a back button pointing to A when I load B from D.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution from nburk converted in swift with the use of storyboard :

```
let a = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("aIdentifier") as! ATableViewController
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: a)
let b = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("bIdentifier") as! BViewController
// b parameters here
// b.parameter1 = variable
nav.pushViewController(b, animated:false)
self.presentViewController(nav, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

Where aIdentifier and bIdentifier are the identifier you set inside storyboard editor for each view and ATableViewController and BViewController their respective ViewController classes.